# How to block all outgoing calls?

Tags: calls

I want to block all outgoing calls regardless of who I'm calling since I have finished all my allowance.

I need a way to block all calls because I keep forgetting and I'll exceed my allowance. (I can use VoIP services instead).

Comment: Check if your telecom provider has tools to limit billing cycle usage of voice minutes, sms messages, and mobile data.

Comment: You could also turn on airplane mode, then re-enable wifi so you use wifi only. There should also be an option to turn your ability to make cellular calls. However, doing either of these things will also affect your ability to use mobile data.

Comment: @MorrisonChang not really possible for me.

Comment: @DrZoo like you said no data, which is somewhat annoying. (Plus I had lots of Google Play Credit so this solution below is best for me).

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by DrZoo's idea in the comments, if you have a rooted device and using Macrodroid, you can block all outgoing calls by following the steps below:

1. Open Macrodroid, click on Add Macro.
2. On the Triggers section, select Call Outgoing follwed by the contact(s) you want to block.
3. On the Actions sections, select Air Plane Mode On/OFF then choose Air Plane Mode On (you can choose to keep Wifi and Bluetooth on). Add the Wait Before Next Action and set it to 1 second.
4. Add the Air Plane Mode On/OFF action, select Air Plane Mode OFF.

The image below illustrates the macro when completed. When you try to make a call, the air plane mode will be on, forcing the dialer app to stop the call because there is no connectivity. After 1 second wait, the air plane mode will be set to off, restoring connectivity.

***Disclaimer:*** I am not associated with Macrodroid developer(s), only a user.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Does this trick (enabling Air Mode) works only with root?

Comment: @Suncatcher Yes. Macrodroid needs root access when using "Airplane Mode On/Off".

Answer (score -1):

The app shared by Mark above seems to not be available anymore. I found another alternative - [Block Outgoing Calls](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.toolworld.callblocker.lite). This is also a paid app.